# problems when adding server side control

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a fully HTML project, with complete .CSS file.

The thing is I want to add some asp.net controls like TextBox's and Buttons and what not, but when I add server side controls to it and run the pages it gave me errors I cannot follow because it appears on the tab of the browser.

The error start with control 'txt' of type TextBox..., and then it gives me Navigation Cancelled, and the browser direct me to

> http://youtubedownloader.mybrowserbar.com/cgi/errors.cgi?q=http://localhost:55942/Dar%2520Al-Thaqafah/Default2.aspx&type=dns&ISN=A9B31DEE919345BE838EAF628EAFA22F&ccv=149&cnid=937811&cco=US&ct=1&sc=500

Here is the code of default2.aspx page

```
[%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.vb" Inherits="Default2" %]




   [div class="header"]
        [div class="logo"><a href="Default.aspx"></a></div]            
    [div id="menu"]
        [ul]                                                                       
        [li class="selected"][a href="Default.aspx"]Home[/a][/li]
        [li][a href="Default2.aspx"]Available Books[/a][/li]
        [li][a href="Default3.aspx"]Register[/a][/li]
        [li][a href="Default4.aspx"]Checkout[/a][/li]
        [li][asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server"][/asp:TextBox][/li]
        [li][asp:Button ID="btn" Text="hhhhh" runat="server" /][/li]
        [/ul]
    [/div]      
 [/div]
```

[/div]

I am using Browser IE version 9.
Visual Studio 2005.
Thank you

Comment: ?
Can you show us some code / screen shot of page error etc?

Comment: Can you provide the exact error details what you get on the browser while running?

Comment: @mortb that is the main problem, no errors to show just directly will take me to the link I provide above. Thanks all.

Comment: @Girijaa in the same link you will see this hyper link to define the error 'errors.cgi?q=http://localhost:55942/Dar%2520Al-Thaqafah/Default2.aspx&type=dns&ISN=A9B31DEE919345BE838EAF628EAFA22F&ccv=149&cnid=937811&cco=US&ct=1&sc=500 '

Comment: @user1400575 the link you provide is pointing to localhost and thus the outer world cannot view your error details. Can you please post your 'default.aspx' page code?

Comment: @Girijaa please check the code I have posted this is just a piece of html and only error I got when adding these two server side controls (Textbox, Button)

Comment: Have you built your project? (Pressing F5 or ctrl-shift-b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the code given below:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.vb" Inherits="Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="logo"><a href="Default.aspx"></a></div>            
        <div id="menu">
            <ul>                                                                       
                <li class="selected"><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="Default2.aspx">Available Books</a></li>
                <li><a href="Default3.aspx">Register</a></li>
                <li><a href="Default4.aspx">Checkout</a></li>
                <li><asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></li>
                <li><asp:Button ID="btn" Text="hhhhh" runat="server" /></li>
           </ul>
        </div> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much man, that really worked for me appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Well with the limited information you provided, I guess the problem is that you are adding ASP.NET controls to an HTML page and not an ASP.NET page and that's why you see the errors. The ASP.NET controls are executed by the server and converted into Browser-readable HTML controls. So, you can only add ASP.NET controls to only ASP.NET page.

Comment: Thank you for that, I have copied the html code and past it in default.aspx page. I don't know where the problem is.

Comment: Did you try running it now? If there is error, can you post a screenshot? or the complete error?